# Planning on Trying out Oracle ADF Technology

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-fusion-middleware

I'd like to try the Oracle ADF technology and have tried a sample step by step tutorials on the oracle sites.

Judging from what I have seen, here's my personal comments.

- Drag and Drop operations.  Makes me feel that I am programming Desktop application for the web.
- I havent done any Javascript or CSS coding but I was able to create a simple AJAX functionality
- I didnt bother about cross browser problems.
- The business component mapping are awesome
- JDeveloper made everything quick
- Professional looking site without you not being a CSS/AJAX guru.

With all of these, can I say that Oracle already polish this new technology?  Is this the next big thing in J2EE dev?  Is it worth investing time studying this and will learning this technology allows me greater opportunity? Is there a fair market share on these technologies now?

I have tried doing Web programs using Servlet/JSP only.  Then I tried with Struts and Spring but I often took a long time doing a simple search/update page with these technologies.

I cannot say any Cons for now as I havent done serious web projects with ADF.

What do you think guys?

Thanks

Comment: When I tried to use ADF (2006), it was a crap. Extramamelly heavy and with lots of compability issues. Nowadays I believe that Oracle solved all theses issues. I would give it a try, but I sincerally prefer a JavaScript framework as ExtJS.

Comment: I believe you can use any JS fwk you want with ADF Faces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first used Jdeveloper back in 2000, when it was a really ropey product.  It has improved beyond all recognition since then.  In particular Oracle have put a lot of work into database interaction (not surprisingly) and wizard-driven / visual development tools.

In terms of serious developmment, Oracle is using the product to build Fusion Apps, the next generation of E-Business Suite.  This makes JDeveloper the flagship tool of Oracle's onward march towards World Domination.

The main problem is, most Java developers are wary of proprietary tools.  They prefer Eclipse, Hibernate, etc.  It remains to be seen whether attitudes will change now that Oracle  owns Java.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare it to other technology stacks that you needed to accomplish task, ADF is all-in-one solution that will let you focus on getting the job done, instead on focusing how to make solution A talk with solution B...
However, on the other side, oracle licencing fees is something that you need to count on. ADF is free if you buy licence for Web Logic server. However if you plan to use some other Application Servers with your solution, you'll need to pay runtime licence.

In every case, it doesn't hurt to learn new things :)

Comment: Check out ADF Essentials - ADF running on community edition Glassfish, fully supported, no licensing fees.http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/adfessentials-1719844.html